# PHP: PDO (SQLite) user input - Security?

Tags: php, security, pdo, xss, sql-injection

I'm writing a litle Q&A webapp which will allow Internet users to submit answers to questions (only answers can be submitted, not questions).

I'd like your thoughts on my method that receives the user input and inserts it into the database, mainly from a security point of view. I've actively tried to address the weight of the payload (`strlen()`), XSS (`htmlspecialchars()`), SQL injection (`prepare()`), and that the user is submitting an answer to a question that actually exists (by executing a `SELECT` query "behind the scenes").

```
public function submitAnswer($qid, $payload) {
    // escape/sanitize input
    $answer = htmlspecialchars($payload, ENT_QUOTES);
    $unix_time = time();
    $qid = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $qid);

    // get length of question from db
    $this->sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT question, LENGTH(question) as length FROM questions where id = :id");
    $this->sth->execute(array(':id' => $qid));
    $this->sth->bindColumn('length', $q_length);
    $result = $this->sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

    // make sure question exists and check the combined length of q & a
    if ($result && ($q_length + strlen($answer) < 130)) {
        try {
            $this->hsth = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO answers (unix_time, qid, answer) values ($unix_time, :qid, :answer)");
            $this->sth->execute(array(
                ':qid' => $qid,
                ':answer' => $answer
            ));
            return array('status' => '0', 'unix_time' => $unix_time, 'qid' => $qid, 'length' => strlen($answer));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return array('status' => '1', 'unix_time' => time(), 'message' => 'db error');
        }
    } else {
        return array('status' => '1', 'unix_time' => time(), 'message' => 'invalid input');
    }
}
```

To be more precise, do the functions (`htmlspecialchars()` and `prepare()`) offer sufficient protection against XSS and SQL injection?

Comment: Do you have any specific question here? Questions just asking for a recommendation or judgement are off-topic here, sorry.

Comment: To be honest I was humbly expecting a "review" but I've updated the OP with a more precise question.

Comment: Yes, that should be fine, _if_ they are used consequently everywhere. You have to add CSRF protection to your list, though. And maybe a watchdog for DOS/DDOS. But hey...

Comment: If you want a review, [codereview.se] is the place to go.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is correct to use on `$answer`, but you should _not_ use it before storing in the database. Best practice would be to store the original unescaped value, and later call `htmlspecialchars()` on the value when you _retrieve_ it from the database to display in HTML. So you are not usually storing XSS-escaped HTML in the database, only escaping it at the time you output it.

Comment: You might want to swap out `htmlspecialchars()` for `htmlentities()` -- the latter covers every non-alphanumeric instead of just the main HTML ones.